# Code to automatically remove users that have numbers from 1-500 at the end

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, user-accounts

I recently ran a program that automatically generates 500 users on a virtual machine, and it is making it lag on the lockscreen. Basically, it generates 500 users in the format of: "userX (user1, user2, user3 etc.). I was wondering if there could be a batch script / powershell script / just anything that could be done to remove all of these users. The process can be done manually using `net user userX /del` but it could probably be automated using the same command again but with numbers counting up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /L %a in (1,1,500) do @net user user%a /del
```

Or if in a batch file:

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,500) do @net user user%%a /del
```